# How to get only variable names in TCL expression which is passed to the proc

Tags: string, tcl

I have an expression which I'm passing through `proc`. My procedure should return all the variable names.

e.g.: Calling `getvalue {expr [$a + $b]}` should give me `$a` and `$b`.

```
proc getvariables {q} {
  set aa [lsearch -inline -all [split $q " "] {*$*}]
  puts $aa
}
getvariables {expr [$a + $b]}
```

That is my code. It is returning:

```
{[$a} {$b]}
```

But it should return only:

```
$a $b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you split your string by a space character to get a list with four items:

```
expr
[$a       <--- matches *$*
+
$b]       <--- matches *$*
```

After that you searched for any list items matching `*$*`, which matched `[$a`] and `$b]`.

You probably want to use `regexp` instead in order to be more specific with your matching requrements.  The pattern `\$\w+` matches anything starting with a literal dollar sign followed by one or more alphanumeric+underscore characters.   Please finetune the regex as needed.

```
proc getvariables {q} {
  set matches [regexp -all -inline {\$\w+} $q] 
  return $matches
}
getvariables {expr [$a + $b]}
```

This returns list `{$a} {$b}`.   The curly braces are displayed around the variable names in this list context because start with a dollar sign, but are not literally in the value of the list items. To confirm this, call `join` on the resulting list to get the string `$a $b`

Comment: There are other syntaxes for variables too, especially array elements. Don't know whether that matters.

Comment: Yes, good point.   There are many contexts when a variable name is not preceded by a $.   `set <varname>`, `lappend <varname>`, `array <array_subcommand> <array_varname>` to name a few.